# How to extend the UITableViewCell when touched

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, height, touch

I have a `UITableView` in which I have used `UITableViewCell`, I need to increase the height of `UITableViewCell`, when I have to touch it. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it like this- When you will touch the UITableViewCell, the height of the cell should be increased?